# App Store Connect Submit for Review Error "ENTITY_UNPROCESSABLE.BETA_CONTRACT_MISSING"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

On 28th October as I was uploading a new build to Test Flight suddenly all of my previous versions and builds expired. I was able to upload new builds from Xcode with no problem and the build appears as "ready to submit" but when I try to add a tester or a group and submit for review, I get the error `"There was an error processing your request. Please try again later."`

[image: pic1]

I inspected network activity on Chrome and error was on "betaAppReviewSubmissions" call with error:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "c7c9f253-4fbe-4639-9a16-363e600cd2d0",
    "status" : "422",
    "code" : "ENTITY_UNPROCESSABLE.BETA_CONTRACT_MISSING",
    "title" : "Beta contract is missing for the app.",
    "detail" : "Beta Contract is missing."
  } ]
}
```

There was no error before, I've submitted for review several times. This suddenly appeared. What is this "Beta Contract" and how to solve this issue?

Comment: related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691372
not too helpful unfortunately - anecdotally this appears to happen when adding/removing testers. Could be some kind of provisioning/signing issues masquerading behind the beta contract error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved after contacting Apple Developer Support. It took approximately a week.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, because the Developer account is expired, you should check if you need to renew the developer account.